# Magento : Pass Image Id to Another Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, default, media-images

We have Two product, First which has many images and second is sample product of that product. we don't want to upload same product images as first product already have that. we just want to pass that image id to sample product.

Any idea?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B16pwFWrEtUVV0pjR0dxUDlHakE/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: So What you have to do with this? You want to show same image on that sample product view page?

Comment: Yes same images for sample product

Comment: So you need to do something like this, fetch parent product detail on sample product page and display images of that.

Comment: By using this implementation we have to change everywhere like cart checkout etc.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `addImageToMediaGallery` function it requires a file path

That is already available to server.

```
$imageDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog/product' . DS . $imageName;
$sample_product->addImageToMediaGallery($imageDir, null, false, false);
$sample_product->save();

$sample_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sample_product->getid());

$gallery = $sample_product->getData('media_gallery');

$arr = end($gallery['images']);

if (isset($arr['value_id'])) {
    $valueId = $arr['value_id'];
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
    $galleryValueTable = 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value';

    $writeConnection->update(
        $galleryValueTable, 
        array(
            'label'     => $referenceId,
            'store_id'  => '',
        ),
        array('value_id = ?' => $valueId)
    );
}
```